# Conditional expectation of depended random variables

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I need some example of depended random variables $\xi, \eta$ such that $\Bbb{E}[\xi|\eta] = \Bbb{E}[\xi]$.

Comment: Just find two random variables with different distributions and the same expected values.

Comment: Say a four sided die can come up $\{\pm 1, \pm 2\}$ with equal probability for each.  Let $\xi$ denote the value of the die and let $\eta$ be the event "the toss is odd".

Comment: The left hand side is a random variable and the right hand side is a number, so I think that there is some problem in the expression that you want to prove.

Comment: @JimmyR.: I interpret this as requiring that the left side should be a constant random variable.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I wasn't clear enough. I didn't mean to use these variables as $\xi$ and $\eta$, but as $\xi\mid\eta=0$ and $\xi\mid\eta=1$ for example (and let $\eta$ be some Bernoulli variable).

Answer (score 3):

Let $\xi$ be a normal random variable with mean zero, and let $\eta = |\xi|$.

Comment: More generally, can't we just let $\xi$ have a symmetric distribution with mean $\mathbb{E}(\xi)=\mu$ and let $\eta = | \xi- \mu |$?

Comment: @David: Almost any.  It doesn't work, for instance, if $\xi$ is $\pm 1$ with probability $1/2$ each, for then $\eta$ is independent of $\xi$.

Comment: Ah, good point and nice example.